# why we are again creating struct variable from struct object?

Tags: c++, declaration, typedef

I am beginner in c++. Here is my doubt why in this program they are again creating struct variable from the previously created struct object ?
Here is the example:

```
typedef struct prog1
{

int a,b;

}*obj1;

int main()
{

obj1 moc=new prog1(); // why again creating object for *obj1 object?
moc->a=10;  // why dont we use obj1 -> a=10;

}
```

thanks

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov It's valid C++. Not a very nice piece of C++, but C++ nevertheless.

Comment: `moc->a` is UB, as moc is uninitialized.

Comment: you'll have a segmentation fault since no memory is allocated for moc.

Comment: Sorry for that i edited now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it more clear use an alias declaration instead of the typedef definition.

```
struct prog1
{

int a,b;

};

using obj = struct prog1 *;
```

So the name `obj` is an alias for the type `struct prog1 *`. `obj` is not a variable.

So in this declaration

```
obj1 moc;
```

there is defined the variable `moc` with the type `obj`. This declaration is equivalent to the following declaration

```
prog1 *moc;
```

That is there is declared a pointer of the type `prog1 *`.

Pay attention to that the pointer is not initialized. So it has indeterminate value. As a result the following statement

```
moc->a=10;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Why do you use `struct` in the alias? It is not needed.

Comment: @walnut For clarity.

Answer (score 5):

`obj1` is not an object but a type definition, because it is part of the `typedef` definition. Namely, it is a type of `prog1*` (a pointer to `prog1`). The `obj1 moc` declares a variable of this type, i.e. `moc` is a pointer to `prog1`.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to use  `typedef` before struct. you can directly use prog1 as a type.
like this:

```
struct prog1 {
    int a,b;
} obj1;   //<---create right away the obj1.

int main() {
   prog1 obj2;  //<---another object created.
   prog1 *pObj = new prog1();

   obj1.a = 10;
   obj2.a = 20;
   pObj->a = 30;
   //...
}
```

or you don't even need the `prog1` struct name. like this:

```
struct {
    int a,b;
} obj1, obj2, *pObj;   //<---obj1 and obj2 already has allocated space for data.

int main() {
   pObj = new prog1();  //<---allocate data space that will be pointed by pObj.

   obj1.a = 10;
   obj2.a = 20;
   pObj->a = 30;
   //...
}
```